# Making a function that prints any variable given as parameter in c++

Tags: c++, printing, cout, console.log

I love debugging by printing, since you can print lots of things and investigate your code.
But I don't like `cout<<`ing all the time, since it is a bit hard to write, and you have to add new line to cout, which means if you want to print something you have to
`cout<< something<<"\n";`
I was writing a function in Javascript, which was easy to implement:

```
function p(s){
    console.log(s)
}
```

which makes it very easy to print a thing. Example:

```
let name = "Alex";
let surname = "De Souza";
p("Name is:");
p(name+surname);
p(len(name));
```

But when it comes to c++, do I have to write like:

```
void p(int i){
    cout<<i<<"\n";
}
void p(string s){
    cout << s<<"\n";
}
void p(bool b){
    cout << b << "\n";
}
.
.
.
```

or is there an easier way that will let me implement it simpler?
I tried auto, but it is forbidden in function declaration.

Thanks.

Comment: `template <typename T> void p(T const& t) { cout << t; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a templated function.

This would look like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void p(const T& t) {
    std::cout << t;
}
```

What this does, is that when you hit compile, it automatically create functions using this template, with `T` replaced with the types you have used in your program. So if you were to write:

```cpp
p("Hello World!\n");
p(10 + 20);
```

It would create two functions, one where `T` is replaced with `const char[]` (a C string) another where `T` is replaced by `int` and would use them.

Comment: Although in the first case `T` would be replaced with `char const[N]` and not `std::string`

Comment: Ah you are right, I always forget that strings default to C strings. I will edit my post.